# Acquiring payment service ID

Tags: php, object-oriented, finance

I have a utility class, called `Bills`, that extracts some information from a `billId` and a `paymentId`. I'm pasting the whole class here for completeness, you don't need to understand the algorithm behind all functions to be able to answer my question.

```
<?php

class Bills {
    private $typeAndServicePaymentIdMap = [
        0 => 13,
        1 => 4, // water
        2 => 1, // electricity
        3 => 5, // gas
        4 => 2, // landline
        5 => 3, // cellphone
        6 => 6, // municipality due
        7 => 6, // municipality due type 7
        9 => [
            'default' => 24, // traffic due
            '001' => 38, // traffic fine
            '002' => 38, // traffic fine
        ],
    ];

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(File_Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getType($billId)
    {
        return substr($billId, -2, 1);
    }

    public function getAmount($paymentId)
    {
        $paymentId = str_pad($paymentId, 13, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $amount = ltrim(substr($paymentId, 0, 8), '0') . '000';

        return $amount;
    }

    public function getCompanyCode($billId)
    {
        return substr($billId, -5, 3);
    }

    public function getPaymentServiceId($billId)
    {
        $type = $this->getType($billId);

        if (key_exists($type, $this->typeAndPaymentServiceIdMap)) {
            return $this->calculatePaymentServiceId($type);
        } else {
            $this->logger->errorLog('Type ' . $type . ' is not defined in the $typeAndPaymentServiceIdMap.');
        }
    }

    private function calculatePaymentServiceId($type)
    {
        $paymentServiceId = $this->typeAndPaymentServiceIdMap[$type];

        if (is_array($paymentServiceId)) {
            return $this->createPaymentServiceIdFromCompanyCode($paymentServiceId);
        } else {
            return $paymentServiceId;
        }
    }

    private function createPaymentServiceIdFromCompanyCode($paymentServiceId)
    {
        $companyCode = $this->getCompanyCode($billId); // TODO: fix this, we don't have $billId here

        if (key_exists($companyCode, $paymentServiceId)) {
            return $paymentServiceId[$companyCode];
        } else {
            return $paymentServiceId['default'];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is in `getPaymentServiceId()`. Here is what this function does:

1. If the type is found in the `type` -> `paymentServiceId` map, it checks the value defined for `$type` in the map. For example, if `$type` is 1, it gets the value for 1, which in this case is 4.
2. If the `paymentServiceId` (the value that was retrieved in the previous step) is not an array, it just returns it. For example, if `type` is 1, the value is 4, and it is returned as-is.
3. However, if the `paymentServiceId` is an array, we need to calculate the company code (calculated using `$this->getCompanyCode()`) to be able to get a `paymentServiceId`, and as you can see, to do that, we need `billId`. In the current mapping, only a type of `9` would result in this calculation. All other `type`s would not require this.

In other words, if `createPaymentServiceIdFromCompanyCode()` is called, it needs `billId`. If not, `billId` is not needed. My problem is that I don't want to pass `billId` as an argument down the chain when it is only needed for one `$type`.

Is there a better way of structuring this class to achieve what I want, or do I have to just pass `billId` down the chain every time?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid passing `$billId` argument down the chain within `Bills` class - "stub" chain of those methods.
Let the `getPaymentServiceId()` method do all the "processing" work. Remove `calculatePaymentServiceId` and `createPaymentServiceIdFromCompanyCode` methods. 
 The final result should look like the following:

```
class Bills {

    private $typeAndPaymentServiceIdMap = [
        0 => 13,
        1 => 4, // water
        2 => 1, // electricity
        3 => 5, // gas
        4 => 2, // landline
        5 => 3, // cellphone
        6 => 6, // municipality due
        7 => 6, // municipality due type 7
        9 => [
            'default' => 24, // traffic due
            '001' => 38, // traffic fine
            '002' => 38, // traffic fine
        ],
    ];
    private $logger;

    public function __construct($logger = "") {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getType($billId = "") {
        return substr($billId, -2, 1);
    }

    public function getAmount($paymentId = "") {
        $paymentId = str_pad($paymentId, 13, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $amount = ltrim(substr($paymentId, 0, 8), '0') . '000';

        return $amount;
    }

    public function getCompanyCode($billId = "") {
        return substr($billId, -5, 3);
    }

    public function getPaymentServiceId($billId = "") {
        if (!$billId) {
            $this->logger->errorLog('billId is required!');
            return;
        }
        $type = $this->getType($billId);
        $companyCode = $this->getCompanyCode($billId);

        if (key_exists($type, $this->typeAndPaymentServiceIdMap)) {
            $paymentServiceId = $this->typeAndPaymentServiceIdMap[$type];
            if (is_array($paymentServiceId)) {
                return (key_exists($companyCode, $paymentServiceId))? $paymentServiceId[$companyCode] : $paymentServiceId['default'];
            } else {
                return $paymentServiceId;
            }
        } else {
            $this->logger->errorLog('Type ' . $type . ' is not defined in the $typeAndPaymentServiceIdMap.');
        }
    }
}

// $logger object
$bill = new Bills($logger);

var_dump($bill->getPaymentServiceId("00190"));  // int 38
var_dump($bill->getPaymentServiceId("00390"));  // int 24
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The reason I broke that method down into two more methods is the `if` statements. I don't want to have two if statement inside each other and am looking to bring down the complexity.